# symfony 1.4 redirect to action with object routing parameter

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have trouble redirecting an object (or routing object) from an action to another action.

my actions file:

```
protected function example(...){
  ...
  $object = Doctrine::getTable('object')->findOneById(1); //for example
  ...
  //dunno how to pass $object to executeShow 
  $url = $this->generateUrl('object_show', array('sf_subject' => $object));
  $this->redirect($url);

public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request){
  $this->object = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```
protected function example(...){
  ...
  $object = Doctrine::getTable('object')->findOneById(1); //for example
  ...
  //this worked :)
  $this->getRequest()->setParameter('sf_subject', $object);
  $this->forward('module', 'show');
}
public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request){
  $this->object = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
  ...
}
```

Comment: You should understand the difference between `redirect()` and `forward()`. `redirect()` will create a HTTP response which will redirect the user to the new url, so will actually issue a whole new request. `forward()`, on the other hand, is being done within the original request and passes the request to another action of your choice. (all within the same Symfony run)